# reading and editing contents of file

Tags: c#, string, file-io

I have a file which is in this format:

```
AA
AA AA AA
AA AA AA AA AA AA
AA AA AA
file.txt
0
```

Where AA represents a one or two digit number (the length of each doesn't have to be 2), and file.txt is the name of a file. I need a very fast method to obtain the file name. Also, I need to replace the final 0 with 1. If there is no 0 in the file at the end (its optional), I need to append 1 on a new line. Here is my current code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("\r\n1");
string txt = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);
string[] lines = txt.Split('\n');
string name = lines[4];

if (lines.Length != 6) // Check if EOF is 0 or not.
    txt += sb.ToString();
else
    txt = txt.Substring(0, txt.Length - 1) + '1'; // Replace 0 with 1.

File.WriteAllText(args[0], txt);
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

However, I was wondering if there was even a faster way to do this (without having to load the file in memory maybe). I have to process tons of files like this, so saving tenths would be extremely useful.

Comment: So the filename will always be lines[4]?

Comment: Are you getting the filename from the text inside the file or do you want it from its name on the os?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23: Yeah, and if there are 6 lines then I'm certain there will be 0 or 1 at the end.

Comment: @BaliC: I'm getting the filename from inside this file, not from anywhere else.

Comment: Why are you using a StringBuilder just to hold const? It's completely unnecessary and will slow you down. Just do `txt += "\r\n1";`

Comment: My guess is that if you are dealing with less than hundred of thousands of file, performance will not be an issue

Comment: @Charles: You're right. I have no clue why I didn't do that in the first place.

Comment: @Eric: But still, it would be to nice to learn how to optimize code.

Comment: I wonder which person downvoted this question; at the very least make a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(args[0]));
string name = lines[4];

if (lines.Length != 6) // Check if EOF is 0 or not.
    lines.Add("1");
else
    lines[5] = "1";

File.WriteAllLines(args[0], lines);
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Comment: There is no method called Add in string[].

Comment: But there is no ToList method in NET 2.0 and that's what I'm using. :s

Comment: Oh. Of course. I completely forgot about List<T>. Thanks, it works great now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Loading the complete file into memory will most likely be your fastest choice if filesize is below min(MemoryPageSize, FSBlockSize), typically 4K

So assuming You have the contents of the file in a string, methinks using something like

```
int n;
if (content.EndsWith("\r\n0")
{
  n=content.Length-3;
  content=content.Substring(0,n+2)+"1";
}
else
{
  n=content.Length;
  content=content+"\r\n1";
}
```

and write the String out to the file. This will save you from the rather expensive Split()

for the filename we continue as follows:

```
int p=content.LastIndexOf('\n',n);
String filename=content.Substring(p+1,n-p);
```

Comment: Works pretty good. I did not know Split() would slow things down a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for speed, then you want to use FileStream.Read to a temporary buffer. Here is something I threw together that might help point you in a slightly different but faster direction:

```
StringBuilder filename = new StringBuilder();
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
    while (stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1) > 0)
    {
        char c = (char) buffer[0];
        if (char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsPunctuation(c))
            filename.Append(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, the numbers AA are actually in hexadecimal so they can include A-F. If that happens, the filename won't always come correctly.

Comment: If that's the case you would have to do some conversion of hext to string