# Javascript - Read file and compare content

Tags: javascript, file, oracle-apex

I'm having a file which contains a couple of space separated (or comma separated, it will be editable) serial-numbers (all unique).

Now through my Oracle APEX I get one serial-number. My goal is to check if this serial code which could be passed on to a parameter of obtained through `$v('P#_SERIAL_ID')` is equal to one of the serial-numbers in the file.

Is this even possible within Javascript? If so, is there an existing function/code to achieve my goal?

Stackoverflow questions that didn't help me but look alike:

[Javascript-read-file-contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265091/javascript-read-file-contents)

[C#-reading-and-editing-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617533/reading-and-editing-contents-of-file)

[Java-string-comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436901/compare-content-of-two-text-files-and-split-words-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without JavaScript. Import your file into Apex through an Data Load Wizard Page so you will have the content of your file into a table. This way you can compare your information through some kind of SQL validation.

If you don`t like the Data Load Wizard Page you can add a file browse item on a simple page that will take your file and save it as a blob into the database. From there you can again process the file and compare the values.